# How to get posts from Google My Business API

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-my-business-api

How do I get my own posts from Google My Business API as a list to display them dynamically with javascript in my website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a HTTP call to this google api :

https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/accounts/list

You should get a json format response that you can traverse as needed.